# Why is my document.querySelector() returning a [object HTMLDivElement] instead of the value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I have the value `60%` stored inside a `<div class="value-container"> 60% </div>`, however when use this query function `document.querySelector(.value-container)` to get the value, I get this response instead: `[object HTMLDivElement]`

Find below my HTML code:

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="circular-progress">
            <div class="value-container"> 60% </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            let testing = document.querySelector('.value-container');
            console.log("Testing: " +testing);
        });            
    </script>

</body>
```

This code above yields:

```
Testing: [object HTMLDivElement]
```

The desired yield is:

```
Testing: 60%
```

How do I capture the value stored inside my `<div class="value-container"> 60% </div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other commenters are correct - you need do something with the object you get back from your querySelector.

But if you only care about the raw text (which it looks like in this case as you just want the 60% value), then `document.querySelector('.value-container').textContent` is slightly more efficient than `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, query selector returns an element, but to get its inner value
document.querySelector('.value-container').innerHTML should be added